# Operating system loader

Tags: operating-system, loader

Can we say Whenever loader loads program in ram from hard disk it is become process. As process is running instance of a program or program in execution. It is correct or wrong? Please explain. Which is correct defination of process?

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia [a process is the instance of a computer program that is being executed by one or many threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)), so your definition is correct if by loading a program you mean loading its code and data to RAM and preparing necessary environment.

I highly recommend reading linked Wikipedia article, because it explains it quite well.